# PHP FPM docker image, opcache File Cache keep disabled

Tags: php, docker, opcache

I'm trying to turn to Enabled "Zend OPcache - File Cache" in a docker PHP-FPM image. Currently, it's Disabled and the time to render a basic page on a Symfony website takes about 15 sec instead of 150ms.

I'm using the php-fpm-8-2-1 image on Docker which works with other containers like:

- redis
- psql
- node
- maildev
- nginx

All work fine except the php image has a part of Zend OPcache disabled.

[PHP info - Zend OPcache](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLiGy.png)

I try multiple solutions to turn "on" the File Cache but it didn't work.

In following, there is my docker-compose file, my Dockerfile (of php) and my opcache.ini file (I have one to override the default config.

```yaml
# docker-compose.yaml

version: '3.8'

networks:
    dev:

services:
    php-fpm:
        build:
            context: php/php8-2
        restart: always
        networks:
            - dev
        depends_on:
            - db
        volumes:
#            - ./php/extensions/apcu.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-apcu.ini
            - ./php/extensions/opcache.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-opcache.ini
            - ./../projects/:/var/www
```

My PHP-FPM image build:

```
FROM php:8.2.1-fpm

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends vim bash-completion libssl-dev zlib1g-dev curl git unzip libxml2-dev libpq-dev libzip-dev && \
    pecl install apcu xdebug-3.1.3 && \
    docker-php-ext-configure pgsql -with-pgsql=/usr/local/pgsql && \
    docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) zip intl opcache pdo pdo_mysql pdo_pgsql pgsql && \
    apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

COPY --from=composer /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

WORKDIR /var/www

CMD composer i -o ;  php-fpm

EXPOSE 9000
```

```ini
; opcache.ini

zend_extension=opcache.so

#extension=opcache

[opcache]
opcache.enable=1
opcache.enable_cli=1
opcache.memory_consumption=512
opcache.interned_strings_buffer=64
opcache.max_accelerated_files=50000
opcache.max_wasted_percentage=15
opcache.validate_timestamps=1
opcache.revalidate_freq=60
opcache.save_comments=0
opcache.file_cache_fallback=1

[www]
clear_env = no
```

Consequences of it, my website on Symfony takes about 15 sec to render a page... Which should be render in about 150ms :(.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong, please?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: I find it extremely difficult to believe that a lack of file cache is what's causing your site to take 15 seconds to load. I'd recommend trying to do some profiling to see what's causing the slowdown. There's plenty of options, here's one https://xdebug.org/docs/profiler

Comment: Just to render the phpinfo, it takes about 7 sec...  But I will try to add profiler to get an analyse about what is happening. Keep in touch